# how to show the modified time in a specific format using ls command

Tags: shell

I am trying to use the ls command in linux to show the modified time for file in a specific format, which is 'xx minutes ago', for example, "demo.o: 31 minutes ago"

Comment: do you want to restrict `ls -l` output to only `<filename>: <xx minutes ago>` ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot do this using only `ls` command.
There is option --time-style=+FORMAT in ls, and you can use it to get timestamp:

```
ls -l --time-style="+%s"
```

But still you've got to use external script to do the math of "X minutes ago"